# Inaccessible folder when using Google Drive via terminal

Tags: directory

I access my Google Drive via the terminal using [gdfuse](http://gdfuse.forge.ocamlcore.org/). There is a directory that exists, but I can't seem to access via the terminal:

I have a directory called 'papers'. Within that I want to access 'instructions'. When I do `ls -ltr` I see:

```
?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? instructions
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Jun 12  2017 my_docs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3923 Jul 25  2017 bs237-procedure.txt
```

with the word `instructions` appearing in red. And if I try to `cd instructions` I am told `bash: cd: instructions: No such file or directory`.

However if I use a browser to go into my Google Drive, I can access the directory 'instructions' and the files within it no problem.

Comment: If this question is related to the google drive api please edit your question and include your code.  If this question is related to a third party application called gdfuse then please remove the google-drive-api tag and retag it accordingly

Comment: Make sure your credentials are correct, as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358924) answer.

Comment: When I look at `https://console.developers.google.com` for the credentials, there are none. Is this the problem? If so, why has this been fine for years? I guess they might have been deleted for some reason? But again, why is only this one sub directory affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching and I reached this answer, hope it works for you!

> To read a file, its read permission needs to be set. However, to read a directory and the listing of its files, both the read and the execute permissions need to be set. If they aren't, you get weird errors like the ones you're experiencing.
> To set the read permission on files and the read and execute permissions on directories recursively, use this command:
> `chmod -R a+rX directoryname`

and link to that page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/243999/why-do-question-mark-characters-appear-when-changing-the-permissions-of-director

edit : you can change the folder name, again I saw this on the internet and it seems to work!

Comment: Thank you. I just tried `chmod -R a+rX instructions` but I got the message `chmod: cannot access 'instructions': No such file or directory` (even though it autocompletes in recognition that the `instructions` directory does exist.

Comment: Oh so still not working.
I saw this and I think it worth a shot: change the name of that folder

Comment: And I saw this one but I didn't understand, because I'm not working with these things :)
Try " Factory reset Runtime "

Comment: Simply changing the folder name worked for me! If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Oh so it worked, good :)
I'll edit the current answer, and thank you !